# DirectX Sample using DXUT Failed to create Direct3D device (Debug only)

Tags: directx, directx-10

Quite a strange problem I have here, I am trying to run the DXUT DirectX 10/11 tutorials from DirectX sample browser. They build fine, but cannot be run in Debug mode, as this triggers the error warning "Failed to create the Direct3D device". This is strange as I can run them in release mode. The strangest thing however is that they use to run in Debug mode, and I swear I changed nothing in the day it ran, and the next day that it didn't. A friend also has the same  exact problem, which happened around the same time.

Has anyone ran into this problem and know of a solution, or perhaps know why its happening beyond the obvious, I have a DirectX 11 capable card if you didn't pick that up.

Thanks.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. It works in Release but not in Debug.. When I enable C++ Exception, I see a memory corruption error popping up..

Comment: The answer of @SPIKETHECAT and Robert together solved the problem for me. Just install the Windows 8 SDK in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

I literally just spent all day trying to fix this exact same problem. Here is the solution which should hopefully fix yours too...

I managed to find this article explaining that a recent update, *(26th February 2013 to be exact)*, caused the older version to mess up:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2013/02/26/directx-11-1-and-windows-7-update.aspx

That explains why it was working fine a few weeks ago, and now it just suddenly stopped working I guess!

Following their advice, **I downloaded a trial version of Visual Studio 2012**, and after an hour and a half of installation time, and a system restart, you should have all the new DirectX SDK files that you need.

NOTE: You don't even have to use Visual Studio 2012. The new files should fix your issues for Visual Studio 2010 and older versions I presume!

(Before doing this **I also installed all the latest drivers**, but I don't think that did anything to help, but it's worth upgrading drivers whenever you can, as that has fixed a similar issue I had before).

Hope this helps!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you probably have something along the line of this

```
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)  
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif
```

If you do take a look at the `D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;` on the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204909%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  you will see this

> To use this flag, you must have D3D11_1SDKLayers.dll installed;
>   otherwise, device creation fails.

You should check that you do have that `dll` in your system or you should reinstall the DirectX SDK.

Comment: Installing the DirectX SDK won't fix this... The DirectX SDK (June 2010) release is outdated and no longer has the correct Direct3D Debug Runtime for Windows 7 with the DirectX 11.1 Runtime installed. You have to install the Windows 8.x SDK, VS 2012/2013, or the VS 2012/2013 Remote Debugging Tools packages to get the proper debug runtime installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

The automatic IE10 update is what caused my issue of automatic non support of directx development.  Simplest solution is downloading standalone win8 sdk at...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363

The directx debug layer dll has to be updated.